# Dynamic labels in python

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I need to create a GUI that updates labels from outside of the python file the GUI was written in. I tried doing this with Tkinter but kept getting errors and I have been stuck on it for days. the GUI is a  dashboard for a car I created variables to store values for each of the dials and then I created labels to display these values. when I create an instance of this class from outside of the file and change the values of the dials they do not update on the GUI I keep getting errors in all the ways I've tried to do it below is the current version of my code.

```py
import tkinter as tk.

class Dashboard():
    def __init__(self, rpm_val, speed_val, engine_state, 
                 gear_state,gear_mode_state, drive_mode_val ,error0):
        self.root = tk.Tk()

        self.rpm_dial0 = rpm_val
        self.speed_dial0 = speed_val
        self.engine_state0 = engine_state
        self.gear_state0 = gear_state
        self.gear_mode_state0 = gear_mode_state
        self.drive_mode_val0 = drive_mode_val
        self.error_dis = error0
    
        # root.geometry("700x700")
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.root, width=600, height=60)

        # background image
        self.background_image = tk.PhotoImage(file="dashboard_image.png")
        self.background_label = tk.Label(self.root, image=self.background_image)
        self.background_label.pack()

        # rpm dial
        # self.rpm_val = rpm_val
        # self.rpm_val.set("0 RPM")
        self.rpm_dial = tk.Label(self.root, bg="black", fg="red", text=self.rpm_dial0 +" RPM", font=('Helvatical bold', 20))
        self.rpm_dial.place(x=190, y=220)

        # speed dial

        self.speed_dial = tk.Label(self.root, text=self.speed_dial0 +" KMPH", bg="black", fg="blue", font=('Helvatical bold', 20))
        self.speed_dial.place(x=580, y=220)

        # engine
        self.engine_dis = tk.Label(self.root, bg="black", fg="white", text=self.engine_state0, font=('Helvatical bold', 10))
        self.engine_dis.place(x=380, y=190)

        # gear

        self.gear_dis = tk.Label(self.root, bg="black", fg="white", text=self.gear_state0 , font=('Helvatical bold', 10))
        self.gear_dis.place(x=380, y=210)
        # gearmode

        self.gear_mode_dis = tk.Label(self.root, bg="black", fg="white", text=self.gear_mode_state0 ,
                                      font=('Helvatical bold', 10))
        self.gear_mode_dis.place(x=380, y=230)

        # Drive Mode

        self.drive_mode_dis = tk.Label(self.root, bg="black", fg="white", text=self.drive_mode_val0,
                                       font=('Helvatical bold', 10))
        self.drive_mode_dis.place(x=380, y=250)

        # error

        self.error_dis = tk.Label(self.root, bg="black", fg="red", text=self.error_dis, font=('Helvatical bold', 10))
        self.error_dis.place(x=380, y=280)


        self.canvas.pack()
        self.root.mainloop()



if __name__ =='__main__' :
    pass
```

Comment: We're not going to be able to help you fix your code without being able to see it. Show us enough of the code to demonstrate the issue (try to cut it down if you can, to a [mcve]).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Your code does not create instance of `Dashboard`.  Also it is better to post the full traceback if any.